# Codeigniter loading multiple templates

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter, view

I'm using this [Template library](http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_template.) for Codeigniter.

I can't quite figure out how to use his example, advanced use #3, to load multiple templates. I feel like the loading of a 2nd template is missing from his load_main() function below:

```
function load_main($view = '', $view_data = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
$this->set('nav_list', array('Home', 'Photos', 'About', 'Contact'));
$this->load('template', $view, $view_data, $return);
    //shouldn't this be there?=> $this->load('template2', $view, $view_data, $return);
}
```

Am  I correct? And if so, can you give some hints on how the controller and view files would look?

Here's what the author has for the controller:

```
$this->template->set('nav', 'About');
$this->template->set('title', 'About me');
$this->template->load_main('about');
```

And the template view:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="contents"><?= $contents ?></div>
    <div id="footer">Copyright 2008</div>
<ul class="navigation">
<?php foreach($nav_list  as $i => $nav_item): ?>
    <li class="<?= ($nav == $nav_item ? 'selected' : '')?>">
        <?= anchor($nav_item, $nav_item) ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's missing something, but it's a bit unclear how it does work...

```
function load_main($view = '', $view_data = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    $this->set('nav_list', array('Home', 'Photos', 'About', 'Contact'));
    $this->load('template', $view, $view_data, $return);
}
```

So this method uses the "template" template and sets some nav stuff. `$this->template->load_main('test');` would load views/test.php using the "template" template.

So to use a different template, create a new load method in your template file (and template, obviously)

```
function load_radical_template($view = '', $view_data = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    $this->load('radical_template', $view, $view_data, $return);
}
```

Now `$this->template->load_radical_template('test');` would load views/test.php using the "radical_template" template.

Comment: thanks Stormdrain,that looks like one way of doing it, i was hoping that we wouldn't have to add another method as Jerome's documentation doesn't imply that, but i guess sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do... thanks, -tim

Comment: Oh but it does: "To easily deal with multiple templates, define new load methods in libraries/Template.php". Quoted from the first sentence of section 3 _Advanced use 3: multiple templates_ on the page you linked to.